# i am trying to build an program which calculates your percentage and its giving wrong answer using c++,can anyone guide me where i am going wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
    
int main(){ 
  int maths,science,english;
  char answer; 
    
  std::cout<<"please enter your marks : \n";
    
  std::cin>>maths;  
  std::cin>>science;  
  std::cin>>english;
       
  double percent;
  percent= (maths+science+english)/300;
        
  std::cout<< "your percentage is :"<<percent<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: When you say the wrong answer, what inputs are you providing, what answer are you getting, and what do you expect the answer to be? My _guess_ is that you're not expecting the correct [behavior from integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division).

Comment: Cast any of `math`, `science` or `english` to `double` before dividing, or change the number to `300.0`.

Comment: Change `percent= (maths+science+english)/300;` to `percent= (maths+science+english)/300.0;`.  I consider this *the next most vexing parse* (after *the most vexing parse*), because it is silent but deadly.