# I'm using visual studio and I think that the code that I've written is right but whenever i run the program it always shows percentage=0

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int marks;

float percentage;

cout<<"Marks of Robert are as follows :-"<<endl;

cout<<"78,45,62";

marks=78+45+62;

percentage(marks/300)*100;

cout<<"marks of Robert : "<<marks<<endl;

cout<<"Percentage scored by Robert : "<<percentage<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the same problem as [this stab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057703/i-am-trying-to-build-an-program-which-calculates-your-percentage-and-its-giving) at the question. `marks` is an integer. `marks/300` is still an integer, it doesn't get converted to a `float` until after the division has been computed.

Comment: No it is not. Use a debugger. Int 185/Int 300 is zero. You should use float pointing arithmetic in this case. Try to change marks or 300 to float and you will see your result.

Comment: `percentage = (marks/300)*100;`

Comment: yeah it worked i've converted the 'marks' to float.

Comment: Thnx everybody.. ^_^

Comment: What is the max marks? 300? If so, `percentage = marks*100.f/300;` may give a better result.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `int` cannot have decimals.

so this will solve your problem:

```
percentage = static_cast<float >(marks) / 300 * 100;
```

---

*explanation: casting one of the integers to `float` will cause the compiler to [**implicitly** convert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) others to `float`. so the final result will contain decimals*

Comment: A simpler version: `percentage = marks/300.f*100;` or `percentage = marks*100.f/300;`